# Using Python change Environment Variables

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am having a problem with the environment variables in python. How do I get python to export variables to the parent shell?

I am using ubuntu, python 2.7.4

I get this:

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ
{'HOME':'~'}
>>> os.environ['foo']='bar'
>>> os.environ
{'HOME':'~','foo':'bar'}
>>> quit()
$ echo $foo
    # Place #1
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ
{'HOME':'~'}    # Place #2
>>>
```

My expected output is:

- At Place #1: `bar`
- At Place #2: `{'HOME':'~','foo':'bar'}`

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variables set in a child process (e.g. python) *do not affect* the parent process.

It's a one-way street; if this could be done it would be very easy to exploit shells! The environment variables must be set in the parent process itself. This restriction is *enforced by the operating system* and is not specific to Python.

Note that [sourcing a file](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html) in a shell (e.g. `. script.sh`) doesn't create a new process; but there is no way to "source" Python files.